# Passing in value to an invoked lambda function from node.js function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have successfully invoked a lambda function from within my node file.  It returns 200 and success, but I need to pass in a value to the function I am calling and am unsure how to do that.  I am beginning to learn lambda and believe I am not understanding correctly how some things operate.  I am attempting to pass in an email address to the lambda function.

```
function callLambda(){
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2'

var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
var params = {
  FunctionName: 'UploadDailyRecords', 
  Payload: '{"client_id" : "email@email.com"}'
};
lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);         
});
}
callLambda();
```

Also, I am unsure of the correct format of how to invoke it from the other function to accept a variable from this invocation.  This is the way the invoked lambda is set up on AWS.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  get_clients_email();
  callback(null, "completed");
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What did the final solution look like here? How would it work if I need to pass to attributes in the Payload object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything looks good, you just need to access the payload parameter in your Lambda function now via `event.client_id`.

Comment: can you elaborate?  When I run this and invoke "get_clients_email();", that works, but there is nothing being passed into it.  I need to pass what is in the payload to the lambda. What I am thinking you are saying is in "get_clients_email()", i should make it, "get_clients_email(event.client_id)"?

Comment: That was it.  get_clients_email(event.client_id) made it work.  I was able to console.log to verify the variables were being passed.  Thanks!

Comment: One other thing.  Now that it works, I am trying to pass in something that is not hardcoded as the payload.  From my experience, it has to be in string format.  I tried passing in a hash, it wouldnt accept it.  I tried creating a string around it with clientstring = " ' " + clienthash + " ' " and it wouldnt accept that.  Any idea on how I can pass a hash into it as its string format it seems to require?

Comment: You are currently passing a JSON string in the payload. You can't pass a variable/object/hash whatever directly, you have to convert it such that the entire payload parameter is a valid JSON string.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build that valid JSON string, but I am finding it very difficult. No matter how I try to build it, it is not coming out in the acceptable format.  Very frustrating.  Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried simply building an object in memory and then using `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to a string value?

Comment: I actually did end up building up a string then passing the string into the payload.

Comment: For anyone using Python, it's `event['client_id']`. I know this question is about NodeJS, but this was the top result in Google.

Comment: @MarkB I tried that but I get index errors for every index in the string. Almost as if invoke doesn't parse it out on the other side.